# FT232RQ to FT232RNQ

Tags: ftdi

The FT232RQ has now moved to NRND. FTDI are now listing the FT232RNQ as it's replacement. Looking for confirmation that a FT232RNQ can be a direct pin-for-pin replacement for an older FT232RQ. My circuit uses the internal oscillator so should be a direct replacement

Comment: And so what is the question about the subject that you need answered?

Answer (score 1):

The FT232RNQ links to the same datasheet as the FT232RN so I would say yes. Talk to the manufacturer if you are especially worried about it. It usually a good idea to test it in your product to make sure.